# What does this lines mean in syslog

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

What does these lines means in syslog:

```
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[XXXX]: Failed to get udev device from devnum 9:1: Permission denied
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[XXXX]: Failed to get udev device from devnum 9:2: Permission denied
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[Y]: Created slice User Slice of AAAAA.
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[Y]: Starting User Manager for UID 1001...
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[Y]: Started Session c53 of user AAAAA.
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[ZZZZ]: Failed to enumerate devices: Permission denied
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[ZZZZ]: Failed to get udev device from devnum 9:1: Permission denied
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[ZZZZ]: Failed to get udev device from devnum 9:2: Permission denied
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[ZZZZ]: Failed to get udev device from devnum 8:3: Permission denied
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[ZZZZ]: Failed to get udev device from devnum 8:19: Permission denied
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[ZZZZ]: Failed to get udev device from devnum 8:35: Permission denied
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[ZZZZ]: Reached target Timers.
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[ZZZZ]: Reached target Sockets.
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[ZZZZ]: Reached target Paths.
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[ZZZZ]: Reached target Basic System.
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[ZZZZ]: Reached target Default.
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[ZZZZ]: Startup finished in 6ms.
Mar 16 12:09:33 BBB systemd[Y]: Started User Manager for UID 1001.
```

For more context:

- Codeship (a CI tool) was connecting on the server in SSH and was running a command (this command calls php, postgresql, and has to log some things in a custom log).
- This command seemed to be blocked (no response, but no details on console)
- The served site (nginx, postgresql) was not responding on page that calls postgresql commands.
- I connected in SSH, restarted postgresql service, and the codeship script failed.
- Then everything worked again (postgreSQL is OK).

I searched in PostgreSQL logs, in Nginx logs and in php logs, but found nothing. So I started to dig into syslog. But I'm not an expert. These lines are the lines where I think the problem started but I'm not sure.

- What does these lines mean?
- If it has nothing to do with my actual problem, where should I search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`udev` is a virtual object controlling devices on Unix/Linux system.

As the log said, the process didn't have the permission to get info from `devnum 9:1:`.

Also from [man udev](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#NAME) for systemd:

> Remember to check out whether the CI tool (codeship) has the privilege to read udev info. You can use the user `su - username` and use commands like this to check it `udevadm info -q all -n /dev/your_device` If the user doesn't have the privilege.  Use this to change the device privilege. `chmod 0666 /dev/your_device`. Make sure the user can have **read** privilege.